# How I change default path of llvm?

Tags: cmake, clang, llvm

i have llvm 6.0, llvm 7 and llvm 8 and the default path is for llvm 6.0

/usr/lib/llvm-6.0/cmake

How I change this path?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set `-DLLVM_ROOT=/usr/lib/llvm-8.0` or whatever the path is.

In general, if you have `find_package(Foo ...)` then setting `Foo_ROOT` will take highest precedence in the search.

If you also need corresponding packages like Clang and LLD you'll need to set their `_ROOT` variables too.